# Storm Topology deployment using pre deployed jar

Tags: apache-storm, hortonworks-data-platform

We currently have a jar that contains 6 topologies. To deploy these topologies we currently do 6 separate calls using

```
/bin/storm jar $LOCAL_JAR  $TOPOLOGY_CLASS $TOPOLOGY_NAME $PS_ENV $ZK_QUORUM  -c nimbus.host=$NIMBUS_HOST $STORM_CONFIG_ARGS
```

Looking at the log output, each time the topology is submitted the jar is also uploaded to nimbus i.e there are 6 lines like this

```
9937 [main] INFO  o.a.s.StormSubmitter - Successfully uploaded topology jar to assigned location:...
```

I want to avoid the multiple uploading of the jar. I have tried uploading the jar via scp and placing it in at "uploadedJarLocation" on the nimbus node ( I do this once). 
Then changing my deployment code to use the following for each of the topologies.

```
nimbusClient = NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(storm_conf);
client = nimbusClient.getClient();
...
client.submitTopology(topologyName, uploadedJarLocation, jsonConf, topology.buildTopology());
```

This has sped things up and seems to work fine but I want to ask

**Is this a safe approach, can I safely reference the uploadedJarLocation I pre-uploaded to nimbus via scp?**

**Are there any alternative methods to avoid the multiple jar upload?**

I know about the StormSubmitter.submitJar as an alternative but have found this to be slow.